# Firebase Why does it implement the following code, but it becomes permission denied?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Why does it implement the following code, but it becomes permission denied?

▼react-native code

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
    db.settings(settings);
    db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/memos`)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const memoList = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          memoList.push({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id });
        });
        this.setState({ memoList });
    });
}
```

▼firestore rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid}/memos/{memoId} {
      allow read, write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, in simple JavaScript these rules and this query work correctly with this structure: users(collection)/doc/memos(collection)/doc. Are you sure you pass a correct value if currentUser?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I confirmed it in console.log. Accurate values are arriving at uid.